# Indentation function

Tags: indentation, spaces

I try to write an indenting script. I have the following function, but it is slow:

```
function insertSpaces theLength
  repeat theLength
    put space after mySpaces
  end repeat
end insertSpaces
```

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Yes, there are faster ways. But begin by telling us which programming language you use and what you want to indent.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am using MetaCard and SuperCard. This script works in both.

Comment: There is no such tag on SO and search gives only a couple of results for it here. Maybe you should ask in some other place if you need it urgently.

Comment: Someone answered my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function insertSpaces theLength
  set the itemDel to space
  put space into item theLength of mySpaces
  return mySpaces
end insertSpaces
```

BTW you forgot the return command at the end of your function.